# MySql sourcing file : failed to open file error 2

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

I'm trying to source a file on MySql Terminal, but I'm still having problems, even after entering the entire path of the file, without quotes. 
This is exactly what it shows me:

```
mysql>SOURCE  C:\Users\NewUser\Desktop\DATABASE\premiere_db_MyISAM.sql;
ERROR: 
Unknown command '\U'.
ERROR:
Unknown command '\D'.
ERROR:
Unknown command '\B'.
-------------
SOURCE C:\Users\NewUser\Desktop\DATABASE
-------------

ERROR:
Failed to open file 'C:\Users\NewUser\Desktop\BASIremiere_db_MyISAM.sql', error: 2
```

And the error 2 is dispalyed!

I ascertained that the file exists and that it is saved in the indicated path as file.txt.

I have browsed through similar questions, and I followed the advice trying to fix the problem, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are on Windows?

Still, mysql is expecting the Unix forward slashes. Try this:

```
SOURCE  C:/Users/NewUser/Desktop/DATABASE/premiere_db_MyISAM.sql;
```